# Linq orderby not working

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

I read similar questions and responses on this issue, and tried a number of different ways to do this, but was not successful.  The records show up in the datagrid in random order, not ordered by last name.  Thank you in advance.

```cpp
MyEntities theEntities = new MyEntities();

IEnumerable<NameTable> nameitems = (from myrow in theEntities.NameTable.AsEnumerable()
orderby myrow.NameID
select new NameTable
    {NameID = myrow.NameID,
    FirstName = myrow.FirstName,
    LastName = myrow.LastName});

ObservableCollection<NameTable> nameitemsOC = new ObservableCollection<NameTable>(nameitems);

return nameitemsOC;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably because you're ordering by NameID instead of LastName... try this:

```
orderby myrow.LastName
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do

```
IEnumerable<NameTable> nameitems = (from myrow in theEntities.NameTable.AsEnumerable()
     orderby myrow.LastName
     select new NameTable { 
       NameID = myrow.NameID, 
       FirstName = myrow.FirstName, 
       LastName = myrow.LastName 
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

You sort by `NameID` and not `LastName`.

Also of what type is `theEntities.NameTable`? Maybe you can just create a `CollectionView`, add a `SortDescription` and make this to be the `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid`.

```
ICollectionView myCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(theEntities.NameTable);

myCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("LastName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```